# running a process in background in linux

Tags: java, linux

I want to run this in background.
Here is the content of my .sh file.
Please suggest me

java -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml -jar report-schedule.jar $1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
nohup your_shellscript &
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use & at  the end of your shell command,

`sh YourScriptShell.sh &`

Or you can also use `Ctrl+z` and then write `bg`
bg for background.
To retrieve it in foreground, use `fg`

And that's it :)